# Git branching model for two target environments

Tags: git, web

I'm new to a php project which is versioned via git. The development is distributed to two to four developers who work on their features in separated branches. There are two eternal branches, `master` which is a version which can be deployed to production and `develop` where the current development is integrated and deployed to a test environment.

When a feature is ready for testing, it is merged into a `develop` branch deployed to a test server and the client is going to test the features. This testing process often takes days, sometimes weeks until a feature is approved. When a feature is approved, it is expected to be integrated into the production system immediately.

Since this testing and feedback cycle is pretty slow, the released version on test and production stage are extremely different. It makes it hard to release features to production because it's not possible to merge `develop` into `master` - this would introduce commits/features into `master` which aren't approved by the customer. So every feature branch has to be merged into `develop` and after approval explicitly into `master`.

The slow testing process has one more disadvantage, some features may introduce changes to the same file, which are then integrated so they can be tested on the test server. Which makes it necessary to merge both features to deploy them to the test server and then split them as soon as one of the features is approved and should be deployed to production.

What do you think is a good approach to this situation? Should we batch features and use a fixed release cylce, e.g. once a week?

How can we develop and release features ad-hoc, which branching model would be more appropriate? Or do you think it is totally fine to merge feature branches into `develop` and then into `master` - never merging `develop` into `master`?

Comment: you should check [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: I will give you the same advice someone gave me back in 2012: when in doubt go with [GitFlow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). In your particular case, having release branches solves the "merge feature into master" problem too.

Comment: I think the current approach is inspired by GitFlow and I also think it adds a lot of clutter and rules: which branch merges into another, when to use it etc. I think all the developers (including myself) aren't that deep into git, so there is no defined process. Maybe this is the bigger problem then the branching approach. 

If release branches are used to do last minute tweaking for production roll out, how can it merge back into `develop` if it is specifically optimized for `master`?